# Why can't I use Show with BoxWhiskerChart?

Tags: plotting

[image: Broken Plot]

As you can see in the example image above, I am frequently (but not always) seeing broken line plots when I try to overlay them on top of another plot using `Show`.

This is especially common when plotting on top of a `BoxWhiskerChart`, like above, but I have seen similar artifacts with other combinations of graphics.

It seems like this is probably a bug, but is there a way to work around it?

EDIT: As requested, here is example data and code that reproduces the plot:

```
d1 = {{380.85484658712056, 286.8907758484098, 
    277.5346417980861, -260.9698886255429, -212.00464593127498}, \
    {110.64430107319674, 144.47675987473627, 
    99.93373512263015, -56.177881856948964, 
    29.868418465268505}, {43.12802057882277, -68.16017567325775, 
    14.084311318612794, -36.20880886565394, -81.87985320930875}, \
    {106.99911157544254, -31.663203349930104, -27.570575917736175, 
    61.25746244652189, 
    0.07927149668211417}, {22.786524517448473, -40.71909598294233, \
    -5.457645151349941, -43.881578084779825, -56.53761318830431}, \
    {-23.848477320370613, 6.595731836165279, 49.84565391704327, 
    14.463305228579669, 
    1.7165492496714267}, {-24.233241726829753, -34.41986971239141, 
    71.77402199374153, 
    6.240151571212979, -9.893448889735769}, {27.530209189665232, \
    -39.16537688719902, 7.934274688868037, 21.450252634259602, 
    22.436356176565518}, {5.815740478111099, -19.121655982833524, 
    6.276548184966871, -6.191562514728518, 
    8.163468204721694}, {-1.1095960641474583, -1.8024030708469272, 
    0.5884529855628465, 6.78776508911811, 
    3.2052724335758094}, {1.9945820939801755, -4.961791563938944, 
    0.7207552625366906, -23.034734413964447, 
    23.31037162230476}, {7.791172424307904*^-14, \
    -2.810291307094996*^-14, 5.16543833023678*^-14, 
    1.6887681396769957*^-14, -6.281861164741391*^-14}};
d2 = {{-179.0813322830084, 168.63728065982806, 
    7.613650128893625, -52.78046442802247, 
    4.762591758605045, -5.301920135661192, -20.832115595725575, \
    -4.066331598432242, 14.421498996215757, 2.7434661239850864, 
    4.4509223705660865, 6.406095853462969*^-14}};
Show[BoxWhiskerChart[d1, "Outliers"], ListLinePlot[d2]]
```

Comment: please add copyable code (with sample data) so that people don't have to read your image and have to spend time writing one of their own. Also, I don't think this is a bug... most probably just carelessness with different plot ranges and related options

Comment: Looks like you need to add `PlotRange -> All` for the call to `ListLinePlot`.

Comment: Aha, I thought I didn't need `PlotRange -> All` because the axes are "inherited" from the first plot, but this does indeed fix it! Please write this as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason this is cut off is because the `ListLinePlot`'s `PlotRange` does not cover all the values:

```
ListLinePlot[d2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

When this is included in the `Show` it is still cut off. If, instead, you do:

```
ListLinePlot[d2,PlotRange->All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

it includes all the points. Then, the whole thing will show up when you use `Show`:

```
Show[BoxWhiskerChart[d1, "Outliers"], ListLinePlot[d2, PlotRange -> All]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]